# Including a Boost C++ header causes dlopen() to return error: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE

Tags: c, linux, c++11, boost

The **C** *HelloWorld.so* (shared object) is created by linking in a **C++** *myatomic* library. That C++ library uses a Boost Header:

**myatomic.cpp**

```
...
#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>
...
```

Loading *HelloWorld.so* with [dlopen()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) returns error: **_ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE**

If that Boost header is commented-out, then [dlopen()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) succeeds?

**HelloWorld.yaml**

```
...    
Common:
  Sources:
    - Folder: src
      Files:
        - HelloWorld.h
        - HelloWorld.c
  ConanLibs:
     - CONAN_PKG::myatomic
Linux:
  CompilerOptions:
    - -fPIC
  LinkerOptions:
    - -lstdc++
```

Does Boost C++ under linux need to built with specific options? Maybe gcc vs g++ issues?
Added **-lstdc++** to *HelloWorld* linker options but to no avail. :(

Comment: You link 4 random libraries to HelloWorld.so, but no boost.system. Also all those `-Wno` shouldn't be there either. And no, you can not use boost and C++ interfaces in general from C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A co-worker discovered this fix

> If we're interacting with C++ materials (in this case Boost C++), we
> need to be using g++. The gcc tool, even if supplied with a bunch of
> -lstdc++ args - does not fill the shoes of the g++ compiler, in terms of things like 'linker/loader hints'

The reason for the error *_ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE* is the HelloWorld.so (C program) was not loading a runtime dependent (C++ shared object) *libstdc++.so.6*.  For example,

**$ ldd HelloWorldBAD.so**

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc8a5c5000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f78cf21f000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f78cf431000)
```

**$ ldd HelloWorldGOOD.so**

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd53bba000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f2540003000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f253fe11000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f253fcc2000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2540205000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f253fca7000)
```

**Edit**

It was also found that the [ordering of the -lstdc++ option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58327430/codeblocks-how-to-put-the-linker-option-lstdc-at-the-end-of-the-compiler) is important. (see also this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640642/gcc-link-order-changed))
This command correctly includes the C++ runtime dependencies by placing the -lstdc++ option at the END of the build command

```
/usr/bin/cc -fPIC -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -shared -Wl,-soname,HelloWorld.so ...Lots of Boost Libraries... -lstdc++
```

whereas putting the option BEFORE the Boost libraries does not

```
/usr/bin/cc -fPIC -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -lstdc++ -shared -Wl,-soname,HelloWorld.so ...Lots of Boost Libraries...
```